# Add a directory to the Apache Web Root?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd

I'm running httpd on linux.

I have a folder (`/data/`) that is not in the apache web directory (`/var/www/html/`) that I would like users to be able to access from their browser.  I don't want to move this folder.

How do I make files in this folder accessible to a web browser when the folder is outside the apache web folder?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) to do this quite simply

```
Alias /data /data/outside/documentroot
<Directory /data/outside/documentroot>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Would redirect urls like http://example.com/data/file1.dat  to the file /data/outside/documentroot/file1.dat

Comment: e.g. put that in new file /etc/httpd/conf.d/dir_data.conf and 'sudo service httpd reload' for redhat flavoured linuxes.

Comment: This doesn't allow you to list the directory.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

Answer (score 1):

I used a symlink to pull this off.  I'm wondering if there are any implications of doing this that I should be aware of.

```
ln -s /data/ /var/www/html/
```

Comment: Now you have to enable symlinks on your server, which means that other files on the system could be accessed/compromised if symlinks are able to be created somehow.

Comment: This means you've the FollowSymlinks directive enabled in your configuration; which means external users could access stuff outside the directories you wanted to publish. This can be a problem or not; in general, you want to be sure no symlink is around which could expose data you didn't want to expose in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

I also used symlink with a name like this:

```
ln -s /data/ /var/www/html/data
```

Then go to the URL: http://your_server_ip/data

Comment: In an environment remotely concerned with **security** this will not work.

Comment: I second @chicks - if the  server is correctly configured, this really shouldn't work. If it does work, you have some serious security issues.